# Is there a technical reason for no implicit conversion from DBNull to nullable types?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Is there a technical reason why there is no implicit conversion from DBNull to the various nullable and/or sql types? I understand why the conversions don't currently happen, but don't understand why an implicit conversion wasn't created at the time or added in subsequent versions of the framework.

*Just to be clear, I'm looking for technical reasons, not "because that's they way they did it" or "I like it that way".*

Comment: @DanielPryden: Ok, so you'd be unboxing it into a different value depending upon if the target was a value or reference type?  Is that what you mean?

Comment: @DanielPryden: The question has been reopened, hopefully this time it'll stay open long enough for you to enter an answer.

Comment: OK, I've rewritten my answer, this time with references to the spec.  Turns out it's actually worse than I thought: at this point, I'm pretty convinced that it's not just a bad idea, it's completely impossible.  Hopefully my answer was worth the wait!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I don't know about the `SqlTypes` case, but there definitely are some technical reasons why adding an implicit conversion between `DBNull.Value` and values of `Nullable<T>` with `HasValue = false` wouldn't work.

Remember, `DBNull` is a reference type, and despite the fact that `Nullable<T>` *acts* like a reference type -- by pretending to be able to take on the `null` value -- it's actually a value type, with value semantics.

In particular, there's a weird edge case when values of type `Nullable<T>` are boxed.  The behavior is special-cased in the runtime to box values of type `Nullable<T>` to a boxed version of `T`, not a boxed version of `Nullable<T>`.

As [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) explains it:

> When a nullable type is boxed, the common language runtime automatically boxes the underlying value of the Nullable(Of T) object, not the Nullable(Of T) object itself. That is, if the HasValue property is true, the contents of the Value property is boxed. When the underlying value of a nullable type is unboxed, the common language runtime creates a new Nullable(Of T) structure initialized to the underlying value.
>
> If the HasValue property of a nullable type is false, the result of a boxing operation is Nothing. Consequently, if a boxed nullable type is passed to a method that expects an object argument, that method must be prepared to handle the case where the argument is Nothing. When Nothing is unboxed into a nullable type, the common language runtime creates a new Nullable(Of T) structure and initializes its HasValue property to false.

Now we get into a tricky problem: the C# language spec (§4.3.2) says we can't use an unboxing conversion to convert `DBNull.Value` into `Nullable<T>`:

> For an unboxing conversion to a given *nullable-type* to succeed at run-time, the value of the source operand must be either null or a reference to a boxed value of the underlying *non-nullable-value-type* of the *nullable-type*. If the source operand is a reference to an incompatible object, a `System.InvalidCastException` is thrown.

And we can't use a user-defined conversion to convert from `object` to `Nullable<T>`, either, according to §10.10.3:

> It is not possible to directly redefine a pre-defined conversion.  Thus, conversion operators are not allowed to convert from or to `object` because implicit and explicit conversions already exist between `object` and all other types.

OK, *you or I* couldn't do it, but Microsoft could just amend the spec, and make it legal, right?  I don't think so.

Why?  Well, imagine the intended use case: you've got some method that is specified to return `object`.  In practice, it either returns `DBNull.Value` or `int`.  But how could the compiler know that?  All it knows is that the method is specified to return `object`.  And the conversion operator to be applied must be selected at compile time.

OK, so assume that there is some magical operator that can convert from `object` to `Nullable<T>`, and the compiler has some way of knowing when it is applicable.  (We don't want it to used for *every* method that is specified to return `object` -- what should it do if the method actually returns a `string`?)  But we still have an issue: the conversion could be ambiguous!  If the method returns either `long`, or `DBNull.Value`, and we do `int? v = Method();`, what should we do when the method returns a boxed `long`?

Basically, to make this work as intended, you'd have to use the equivalent of `dynamic` to determine the type at runtime and convert based on the runtime type.  But then we've broken another rule: since the actual conversion would only be selected at runtime, there's no guarantee that it would actually succeed.  But *implicit* conversions are not supposed to throw exceptions.

So at this point, it's not only a change to the specified behavior of the language, a potentially significant performance hit, and on top of that it could throw an unexpected exception!  That seems like a pretty good reason not to implement it.  But if you need one more reason, remember that every feature starts out [minus 100 points](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2004/01/12/57985.aspx).

In short: what you really want here can't be done with an implicit conversion anyway.  If you want the behavior of `dynamic`, just use `dynamic`!  This does what you want, and is already implemented in C# 4.0:

```
object x = 23;
object y = null;

dynamic dx = x;
dynamic dy = y;

int? nx = (int?) dx;
int? ny = (int?) dy;

Console.WriteLine("nx.HasValue = {0}; nx.Value = {1}; ny.HasValue = {2};", 
    nx.HasValue, nx.Value, ny.HasValue);
```

Comment: Yes, this was worth waiting for.  One small caveat, C# null coalescing operator actually makes the conversion fairly simple (through a different mechanism, which is why I was asking about the framework).  int? i = x as int? ?? null;  This is specific to the C# compiler and the ?? operator, and while any language could of course add the equivalent, it's not inherent in the CLR (which is what I am interested in).

Comment: @jmoreno: Hmm... that's a clever trick with the `as` and `??` operators, I hadn't thought of that one.  That would probably be much more performant than `dynamic`, although I still don't think you could do it as an *implicit* conversion operator, since you'll need to know the appropriate value type.  You could probably do it with an *explicit* conversion operator, although you might want to try an extension method instead, which might be easier to work with.

Comment: right, I don't think you can do it with an implicit operator anymore either. In c# you could write an extension method, you can't do that in VB as it doesn't let you do so for Object because of possible conflicts with late binding. I do have a generic utility function for VB, which works.

Comment: @jmoreno: Isn't it more idiomatic in VB to use free functions anyway?  For example, see `CInt`, `CStr`, and friends.  (By the way: the idea of using this from VB adds an interesting wrinkle.  I wonder if you'd get more interesting responses if you made a point of mentioning that in the question itself.)

Comment: except that they don't return nullables and dbnull throws an exception.As for interesting answers, after having it closed twice I feel lucky to get ANY answer. I did include tags to indicate I was interested in a language agnostic answer.  I guess I could have made it more explicit.I think this is fundamentally a problem at either the CLR or class/structure level.And thinking about how to best fix it now, it might be at the struct level, if they had a constructor that took an object and could return null from that, that would work. That's basically what my generic function does.

Answer (score 8):

The most straightforward explanation comes from [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172138%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> CLR nullable types are not intended for storage of database nulls because an ANSI SQL null does not behave the same way as a null reference (or Nothing in Visual Basic).

Comment: In other words, we purposely didn't do this because we want you to be fully aware of what you are doing.

Comment: @competent_tech: The very next sentence from there is "For working with database ANSI SQL null values, use System.Data.SqlTypes nulls rather than Nullable.", but..."Value of type 'System.DBNull' cannot be converted to 'System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt32'"

Comment: @jmoreno: I think that this is addressed a little further down under assigning null values: `Nulls in System.Data.SqlTypes are type-specific and cannot be represented by a single value, such as DbNull. Use the IsNull property to check for nulls.`